# Prevent Assumed Role Recursion - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

How can I create AWS Config rules **to prevent** Assumed Role recursion. ?
For example:

1. There are 2 accounts A and B and they have Roles A and B respectively.
2. Account A is allowed to assume Role B directly
3. But Role A ***should not be able to*** assume Role B

If there is any other way to restrict the assumption of role, please share.

Your help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you do to enable "Account A is allowed to assume Role B directly"?

Comment: @jarmod I haven't done anything as of now. I don't know how to move ahead with this problem

Comment: In the trust policy of Role B you can deny Role A

Comment: @TamásSallai But I want this concept in general so that it applies to all the role. No role should be able to assume another role. How can we restrict this? Thank you for the help